# Slow upload speed over ethernet from router, but Wi-Fi is getting max speeds

Tags: networking, router, ethernet

I've recently got a new broadband connection, 250/100mbps over fiber, and a new router to go along with it. I've set up my router and it's working fine over wifi, I'm getting the maximum speed, and over ethernet cable I'm getting 250 down, but only 10 up. I've tested this on multiple wired devices, all connecting directly to the router.

I've tried resetting my router(ASUS RT-AC68U), and also tried installing a custom firmware (asuswrt-Merlin), but the issues persist. I've done some googling but it's hard finding any real results when basically searching for 'slow upload speed'.

Any and all input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you confirm you have tried multiple cables?

Comment: How are you validating your upload speed? It would be best to use iPerf and share with us your exact methodology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Twisty Impersonators](https://superuser.com/users/213131/twisty-impersonator) advice I tested with multiple speed tests sites and it turns out there was just my go-to test (swedish site bredbandskollen.se) that was showing low speeds. speedtest.net and fast.com are both showing the promised speed.

Seems there's some kind of connection issue vs bredbandskollen, and it is strange that it only happens on ethernet and not wifi, but I can live with that.